# Why does my UWP app crash when I live edit specific properties in XAML?

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp, liveedit

For instance, as soon as I delete the background/foreground/borderBrush value, the app crashes and debugging stops which I think due to the invalid value (empty string). Also with margin/padding set to 3 values only, e.g. padding="0 0 0" (VS doesn't even give me chance to complete what I'm typing!).

Is there anything I need to change or is this how XAML "live" editing supposed to work?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, I'd report it using the `Send Feedback` button next to the quick launch search on the top-right.  It should give you the option to repro the scenario too.

Comment: I've only ever encountered a crash with live editing when changing a controls template within a style, which I assumed wouldn't have worked anyway. Is this what you are doing?